# allow special characters in folder name under windows?

Tags: windows, character

Is there a way to allow these characters `\ / : * ? " < > |`  in folder name under windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no way that those characters can be included in a filename in normal operations. You *can* use some really nasty "black art" techniques to do all kind of nasties though. Not a good idea.